# Triggering a "Click" event without user input

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a Windows Forms Link Label, "Refresh", that refreshes the display.

In another part of my code, part of a separate windows form, I have a dialog that changes the data loaded into the display in the first place. After executing this other code, pressing "Refresh" updates the data correctly.

Is there a simple way for the dialog menu to "click" the "refresh" Link Label after it has finished altering the data?

Using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For button is really simple, just use:

```
button.PerformClick()
```

Anyway, I'd prefer to do something like:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoRefresh();
}

public void DoRefresh()
{
   // refreshing code
}
```

and call `DoRefresh()` instead of `PerformClick()`

---

**EDIT (according to OP changes):**

You can still use my second solution, that is far preferable:

```
private void linkLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoRefresh();
}

public void DoRefresh()
{
   // refreshing code
}
```

And from outside the form, you can call `DoRefresh()` as it is marked public.

But, if you really need to programmatically generate a click, just look at [Yuriy-Faktorovich's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187821/triggering-a-click-event-without-user-input/3187842#3187842)

Comment: +1 for the alternative to PerformClick.  PerformClick is a hackish approach in production code.  I think it should generally be limited to testing.

Comment: My fault; I assumed it was a button, but it's actually a link label that acts like a button.
Is there a similar method for those?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337532.aspx, but as you said, a separate method is better.

Comment: @Yuriy: many thanks, I didn't know that. I've modified my post ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could call the [PerformClick method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx). But Generally it is better to have the Click event of the button call a Refresh method you write. And the menu call that method as well. Otherwise your menu depends on the button being there.

Edit:

A LinkLabel implements the IButtonControl explicitly. So you could use:

`((IButtonControl)button).PerformClick();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a method to refrech display,  the bouton_click and the dialogBox call this method

```
public void refrechDate()
{
}


private void button_click(...)
{
   refrechData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MyMethod()
{
   // ...

   // calling refresh
   this.button1_Click(this.button1, EventArgs.Empty);

   // ...
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // refresh code
}
```